# Adding an @objc method as an action to a button and getting "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer"

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector

I'm adding an action to my button

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchButton(button)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And I have my @objc method

```
@objc public func touchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let soundNumber = soundButtons.index(of: sender)!   //The index of the button
    ...
}
```

Why am I still receiving

```
Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer
```

Comment: `#selector(touchButton)` or `#selector(touchButton(_:))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature that you are using doesn't match your objc method. The correct selector would be `touchButton(_:)`, not `touchButton(button)`.

Comment: The `(_:)` part is optional.

Comment: I want to have an argument though, I updated my code so you can see something I do inside with that argument

Comment: What is the _: , what does it do

Comment: The `(_:)` specifies a method with a single unnamed argument.

Comment: And what if the named function has more than one Arguments? how to write them in #selector?